# Debug a process that terminates after start

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging

I need to debug a process (starting from an external exe) that terminates immediately after start, so I don't have time to attach. How can I debug it?

UPD I don't have source code of that external exe; I can decompile it, but it's impossible to compile it back

Comment: can you use windbg to step through the external exe? http://labs.snort.org/awbo/windbg.txt

Comment: What is it written in? If managed, code a `Debugger.Break();` call in its start-up code. If native, encode a break-point instruction (int3). Either should prompt you to attach a debugger when the break-point is hit.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, post this comment as the answer. It should be the accepted one IMO.

Comment: @Internal Server Error, it's in .NET, but I don't have the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to launch your process for debug in a suspended state. Visual Studio is capable of that, just invoke the debugger like this:

```
devenv /debugexe yourprog.exe <arguments>
```

The process will start suspended so you'll be able to iterate through first instructions before the crash.

See the detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963725/is-there-any-way-to-start-process-in-suspended-state).

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in VS2012. The VS shell starts, but shows standard welcome screen and debugging session is not started.

Comment: If he has not the code it makes no sense to start it suspended.

Comment: @user626528, you might want to put your .exe name in quotes if it contains spaces. VS2012 works for me.

Comment: @SoMoS, the code is still being run, there is Disassembly, modules are getting loaded - lots of other options.

Comment: It doesn't contain spaces, but it contains "-" symbols. Quotes helped.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to open Visual Studio, go to `File -> Open -> Project / Solution`
 and select the exe.

Press F5 and you will see the exception in the Output window. If you go to the `Debug -> Exceptions` window and select everything you will see the first chance exception before it shutdowns the application.

Note that you don't need the source code at all to do this.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start it with the debugger. This will start the program with the debugger already attached.

If you cannot do that with Visual Studio, you can use the Windows Debugging Tools, part of the [Windows Driver Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg454513). Note that the linked kit is for Windows 8.1, you may need to find older versions if you're not on Windows 8.

Answer (score -1):

You can enable debug mode runtime by placing some piece of code.
write a method as below:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG_SERVICE")]
private static void DebugMode()
{
    Debugger.Break();
}
```

and call this method where you want to start debugging, for example in the OnStart event.
you have to build your code with debug mode. dont forget to remove this piece of code after debugging and want to release.

Comment: It's external exe, I can't put anything into it.

Comment: if it's external exe, but you have the code, if you have not the code you can't debug it. you want to debug a exe without having its code??? debug with what?

Comment: not really. you can easily debug a process without source code

Comment: At least you need the .pdb files. beside that, you didn't mention that you don't have the source code in your question. that misleads the ones who want to answer, like the other answer from @Lasse V. Karlsen.

Comment: actually, having the PDB file is useful but not _necessary_

Comment: without pdb files you have very limited information of exe that you are debugging.